# Date selection for org-add-note

Tags: org-mode, time-date

I want to add notes to a heading but instead of  using `org-add-note`, it should be possible to choose any date I want to have as time stamp.
I use notes partly as Diary so I want to be able to create an entry without having to manipulate it afterwards for the desired date.

I wrote this function to accomplish this:

```
  (defun tietan/org-add-note-ts ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((date (org-read-date))(res)(inp))
      (setq res (concat "- Note taken on <"
                        date
                        "> \\\\\n"
                        (tietan/simplified-read-mb-lines "Insert text (C-j to submit): ") ))
      (setq res (replace-regexp-in-string (regexp-quote "\n") "\n  " res nil 'literal))
      (kill-new res)
      ))
```

Now the questions:

1. Is there a better way to achieve date selection for `org-add-note`? I still have to manually insert the output of this function into the org-heading. `org-capture` would always need a specific configuration for that, which doesn't suit my wish to have it as a possible solution for multiple use cases.
2. Which function could I use to get the same buffer input window you normally get with `org-add-note`?

---

Info:

I copied the multiline block prompt from here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004260 and changed the name to better fit in my personal naming conventions

```
(defun tietan/simplified-read-mb-lines (prompt)
    (let ((keymap (copy-keymap minibuffer-local-map)))
      (define-key keymap (kbd "RET") 'newline)
      (read-from-minibuffer prompt nil keymap)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```lisp
(defun my-org-add-note ()
  (interactive)
  (move-marker org-log-note-marker (point))
  (setq org-log-note-purpose 'note
        org-log-note-effective-time (org-read-date nil t))
  (add-hook 'post-command-hook 'org-add-log-note 'append))
```

This sets `org-log-note-effective-time` to `org-read-date`. Everything else should be the same.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed.
I'm curios of how to find those steps that need to be done. Could you give me a hint of where I can find the procedures a function like `org-add-note` uses, so that in the future I could come up with this (way better) solution myself.

Comment: Do `C-h f org-add-note` to see the documentation of the function. Among other things, it also gives a link to the definition of the function (look for the file name at the end of the first line which says: `org-add-note is a Lisp closure in ‘org.el’.` - that `org.el` is a clickable link that will take you to the definition of the function). Once there, you'll see that it calls `org-add-log-setup` with an argument of `note` (a symbol). Repeating the process, you'll get to the definition of that function: compare it with the function in the answer.